# unintended 301 Redirect occuring on apache localhost

Tags: php, apache, redirect, error-handling, xampp

Running Xampp - unintended 301 redirect occurring. I have added a page to localhost/kinetic/golf when I put this url in, it redirects me to localhost/kinetic/2020/12/15/golf-driving-distance-podcast/. It seems like it's a caching error, or it's not recognizing that the new page has been added. I've noticed that it autofills. So when I put in localhost/kinetic/run (page that does not exist) it redirects to localhost/kinetic/running (page does exist). How do I stop the golf redirect from occurring. Currently using firefox but same issue occurs on chrome.

I have cleared browser cache,
restarted server
restarted computer,
changed port # in config files

Comment: Check your .htaccess file, make sure there aren't any redirects there

Comment: Switch off content negotiation in your http server configuration.

Comment: And reevaluate all redirection rules you implemented somewhere, burried deep in the file system in annoying ".htaccess" files or in the real http server's central configuration.

Comment: So when I go to https://kineticsmp.com/golf/ (wordpress) it works just fine - so would this mean I still need to change the htaccess file or a file within xampp because it's working in production but not locally.

Comment: So you are running WP in a subdirectory locally? Not a good idea, IMHO. You should try and match your dev system to the production "reality" as closely as possible. In this case, meaning set up a local domain to run the project under directly on the root level.